# Whenever I run my cloth simulation, the cloth collides with the 'static' pose of my character, and not the animated poses of that character

Tags: cloth-simulation, pose-mode, collision

I have a very low poly character who I have animated to 'sit up' and then move to a pose. I am running a cloth simulation to drop a poncho from out of frame onto the character. The cloth will collide and interact with the 'default' pose of the character, ie how the character stands in edit mode, but will not collide or interact with the character in pose mode. I have attached two photos to demonstrate this, the first is the pose that the cloth should be colliding with and the second is the 'default' pose that the cloth is actually colliding with. I am very new to blender, so you may have to talk to me like I am a 5-year-old! [image: pose that cloth should be colliding with]

[image: collision with default pose]

Comment: Look on the modifier stack (select character, properties/modifiers.)  Move the collision modifier to the end (bottom) of the stack.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize the collision would apply to the initial pose before the armature movement if the collision was on top of the stack. Makes sense and works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Nathan for the answer!

My modifier stack had the collision on top, which messed with the simulation. I moved the collision to the bottom of the stack and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, and that will close the loop on this question.

Comment: @AllenSimpson Thank you for the reminder.