# How to interact cloth and object when I'm in Pose mode

Tags: cloth-simulation, pose-mode, collision

This is not my creation. I've downloaded it from a website.
[image: screenshot]

When I'm using the *Pose* mode, the skirt didn't interact with the leg. I make the skirt as cloth in the physics properties and using self collisions. And the leg is a collision object in the physics properties. How can I interact with the leg and cloth when I am in *Pose* mode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210539/whenever-i-run-my-cloth-simulation-the-cloth-collides-with-the-static-pose-of apply here?